# Doubt regarding Dhat al-Fudul and Interest

Tags: riba

I have heard that Prophet(s.a) have pawned his Dhat al-Fudul with Abu ash-Shahm Jew, in return for some 30 sa(weights relate to food) of barley for his family. Does it involved Interest? Or did Abu ash-Shahm lend what ever requested without intrest.

Comment: How does it involve interest? The armor was deposited as a security for the loan to be taken back at its return, which is permissible, see e.g.[2:283](https://quran.com/2/283)

Comment: @UmH, thanks for the info. I was having a doubt since the 2nd party was a Jew. Normally in these times, when people pawned something for money they had to pay interest before getting it back (normally in banking system).

Comment: That is not what occurs under Islam. Riba is illegal, even for a non-muslim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant ahadith are:

> #### أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم اشترى طعاما من يهودي إلى أجل، ورهنه درعا من حديد
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) purchased food grains from a Jew on credit and mortgaged his iron armor to him.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/34/21)</sup>

> #### توفي رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ودرعه مرهونة عند يهودي، بثلاثين صاعا من شعير
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) died while his armor was mortgaged to a Jew for thirty Sa' of barley.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/129)</sup>

This is a case of **رهن** (*Rahn*) , whereby something is deposited with the lender as collateral for a loan. If the borrower defaults then the loan can be settled through selling the security. This is permissible in general and proven from the Quran in verse [2:283](http://quran.com/2/283).

The security is returned to its owner on repayment of the loan, there is no condition of paying interest and rather it is well known that interest on a loan is haram, both taking it and [giving it](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/68/92). While various translations may have used the term *pawned* or *mortgaged*, the Islamic version of this transaction does **not** involve interest.

The lender being a Jew makes no difference. He was likely a *dhimmi*, and living under Islamic law even non-muslims could not legally engage in interest. So it is unlikely that the Prophet would have permitted it in a transaction in which he was himself a party.

> كتب رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إلى أهل نجران وهم نصارى: أن من بايع منكم بالربا فلا ذمة له
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ wrote to the people of Najran who were Christians: Whoever of you trades with Riba then there is no Dhimma on us for him (i.e. the treaty of protection is broken)
>
> <sup>— [al-Musannaf ibn Abi Shaybah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/41818)</sup>
>
> قرأت كتاب أهل نجران فوجدت فيه: إن أكلتم الربا فلا صلح بيننا وبينكم
>
> I read the agreement (of the Prophet) with the people of Najran and it was written in it: If you will eat Riba then there shall be no peace between us
>
> <sup>— [al-Musannaf ibn Abi Shaybah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/24687)</sup>